# UITableViewCell wont resize after adding subview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I have a UITableView that I set up to grow dynamically depending on the content, by setting:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

My UITableView consists of a headerView and bodyView to which I insert other subviews after setting up.

I set up my cells with the follow rx:

```
viewModel
   .map { $0.cellViewModels }
   .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "MyCell", cellType: MyCell.self)) { [unowned self] (row, viewModel, cell) in
        cell.viewModel = viewModel
        // Tried adding the following with no luck:
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
   }
   .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

the cell's viewModel call's a setup() method with it's didSet, as follows:

```
var viewModel: CellViewModel? {
    didSet { setup() }
}
```

In my setup, I add a subview to the bodyView of my cell depending on some other factors. ie I may add a picture, a bit of text, etc.

The problem is, when I add my subview to the bodyView of my cell, the cell's height is staying the original height that it was in the xib, and not resizing at that point to accommodate the new view. I've tried calling `self.layoutIfNeeded()` after adding the subview, but no luck. How can I resize my cell after adding a subview to it?

Comment: have you checked your cell constraints?

Comment: @Alexkater Yeah it doesn't seem like there's any constraint problems

Comment: tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
This works for me

Comment: @Brejuro Are you adding constraints to the new subview? The autosizing feature of `UITableView` utilises constraints to determine the desired height for a cell, hence without constraints, no resizing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `tableView.beginUpdates()` followed by a `tableView.endUpdates()` call. Without anything in between.

Comment: This would be after adding the subview right? Trying to think if there's a good way for my tableView class to know when my cell finished adding subviews. I added it to the lines after setting the cell's viewModel but no change.

Comment: @Brejuro there's nothing wrong with your `tableView` that owns it's cells to know about their layout and lifecycle, it feels almost essential. It looks like you should used begin and end updates in your bind operator after setting the model.

Comment: @inokey Thanks inokey, I tried adding this but still the same result.